# Generar color rgba de forma dinámica en librería charts.js

Tags: jquery, charts

Estoy empezando a trabajar con la librería chart.js, aun desconozco muchas cosas. El hecho de rellenar el gráfico dinámicamente creo que lo tengo controlado pero el problema que tengo es el del color. En el ejemplo de la librería los datos como los colores los mete a pelo. Yo necesito un gráfico dinámico  que se creen también los colores de forma dinámica.

```
function nTareasxColaborador(){ 
        let colaboradores=[];
        let tareas=[];

        $.ajax({
            "url": "php/Pl/couario_token.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                objJsonColab = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(objJsonColab, function(i, nameColab){
                    colab="<div>"+objJsonColab[i].name+"</div>";
                     colab=$(colab).text();
                    colaboradores.push(colab);
                    tareas.push(i);
                });

                //Empieza el grafico
                ctx = document.getElementById('tar_x_colab').getContext('2d');
                var tar_x_colab = new Chart(ctx, {
                    responsive: true,
                    type: 'doughnut',
                    data: {
                        labels: colaboradores, //Array creado por mi
                        datasets: [{
                            label: '# of Votes',
                            data: tareas, //Array creado por mi
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                //Este es mi problema
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',

                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true //Se para en 0
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Podrias usar Math.round + Math random para generar numberos entre 0 y 255: `'rgba('+Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0)+', '+Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0)', '+Math.round(Math.random() * (255 - 0) + 0)+', 0.2)',`. Ten en cuenta que esto te daría colores muy aleatorios, pero de la misma manera podrías seleccionar un minimo y maximo tu, para que te genere degradantes entre una gama de rojos por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la siguiente solución.

```
$.each(objJsonColab, function(i, nameColab){

  colab="<div>"+objJsonColab[i].name+"</div>";
  colab=$(colab).text();
  colaboradores.push(colab); //Guardo en array colaboradores el nombre del colaborador
  tareas.push(i); //Guardo en el array tareas el numero de cateas de cada colaborador
  var o = Math.round, r = Math.random, s = 255;
  colorFondo.push('rgba(' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + o(r()*s) + ',' + r().toFixed(1) + ')');

});
```